# Gradle DSL method not found: compile() when switched computers

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

On my home desktop (Ubuntu) my project runs fine but when I open the project at work (ubuntu), the project fails to sync as the message says: 
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly.

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Error:(11,0)
```

This is my module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
      compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

/* Uncomment if you enable ProGuard and you want to automatically upload symbols on build.
parse {
  applicationId YOUR_APPLICATION_ID
  masterKey YOUR_MASTER_KEY

  // Make symbol upload automatic. Otherwise, use e.g. ../gradlew parseUploadSymbolsDebug;
  uploadSymbols true
}
*/
```

and this is the project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'

    }
}


ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "22"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 22
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'` from the `dependencies` closure in `buildscript` to your other `dependencies` closure.  `com.stripe:stripe-android` is a library, not a Gradle plugin.